# Are there existing patents on electronic (web) Q&A forums?

Tags: patent-infringement

We want to add Q&A to our product pages, but don't want to get hit with an infringment. Are their any patents that claim to have invented the electronic Q&A forum for posting questions and answers to a web page?

Comment: To get a more detailed (and on-topic) picture, try posting a separate thread calling for prior art on one of the patent #s given below.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic but hard not to make an exception for this!

A very quick look found this (don't let the titles scare you):

**Answer ranking in community question-answering sites**

[US 8346701](http://www.google.com/patents/US8346701)
Microsoft, Corp

**Providing community for customer questions** (only an application)

[US 20130013546](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130013546)

IBM

Comment: To add, experts-exchange.com also had at least one patent on their method of providing a Q&A website: US6064978. This one is much earlier and broader, but note that neither this nor the Microsoft patent is so broad as to cover the general concept of a "Q&A web forum"... The '978 patent relates to "organizing", "regulating" the "number and complexity of questions" and assigning a "quality" to answers, whereas the Microsoft one relates to finding, linking and ranking similar questions and answers. However, note also that these are only two examples of many, many related patents out there.